# Como corregir este error en sql sobre un COLLATE en un EXCEPT

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Con `COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AS` pude solucionar el error hace un tiempo, pero ahora me sale un nuevo error

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[select_cupos]
    as
    BEGIN
    WITH TablaCTE AS (
    SELECT cu.idespecialidad,convert(char(5),cu.horainicio, 108) as HoraInicio,cu.fecha FROM cupos cu
    inner join Especialidades es on es.IdEspecialidad = cu.idespecialidad
    EXCEPT
    SELECT ci.IdEspecialidad,ci.HoraInicio,ci.Fecha FROM Citas ci
    inner join Especialidades ess on ess.IdEspecialidad = ci.idespecialidad
    EXCEPT
    SELECT es1.IdEspecialidad,cb.HoraInicio,cb.Fecha FROM CitasBloqueadas cb
    inner join Especialidades es1 on es1.Nombre = cb.Especialidad COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AS
    )
    SELECT count(IdEspecialidad) as Cupos, IdEspecialidad
    FROM TablaCTE
    GROUP BY IdEspecialidad;
    END
```

Este es el error que me sale

```
Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Procedure select_cupos, Line 11
No se puede resolver el conflicto de intercalación entre "Modern_Spanish_CI_AS" y "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" de la operación EXCEPT.
```

Comment: Has intentado añadir el COLLATE a los 3 SELECT?

Comment: Si, y pues como tiene un int, me sale el mismo error pero antes de que sea EXCEPT. dice To

Answer (score 1):

Después de utilizar mi bola de cristal y generar datos de prueba, los cuales quedaron de la siguiente forma:

```
CREATE TABLE Especialidades(
    IdEspecialidad int,
    Nombre          varchar(100) 
);
INSERT INTO Especialidades 
VALUES
    (1, 'Medicina General'),
    (2, 'Pediatría'),
    (3, 'Traumatología');

CREATE TABLE Cupos(
    IdEspecialidad  int,
    Fecha           date,
    HoraInicio      time);

INSERT INTO Cupos
SELECT idEspecialidad, DATEADD( dd, fecha, GETDATE()), DATEADD( mi, minutos, DATEADD(hh, hora, 0))
FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3)) e(idEspecialidad),
     (VALUES(1),(2),(3)) f(fecha),
     (VALUES(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17)) h(hora),
     (VALUES(0),(15),(30),(45)) m(minutos);     

CREATE TABLE Citas(
    IdEspecialidad  int,
    Fecha           date,
    HoraInicio      char(5) COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AS);
INSERT INTO Citas
SELECT TOP(200) IdEspecialidad, Fecha,  convert(char(5),horainicio, 108)
FROM Cupos
ORDER BY NEWID();

CREATE TABLE CitasBloqueadas(
    Especialidad    varchar(100) COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AS,
    Fecha           date,
    HoraInicio      char(5));

INSERT INTO CitasBloqueadas
SELECT TOP(50) Nombre, c.Fecha, convert(char(5),c.horainicio, 108)
FROM Cupos c
JOIN Especialidades e ON c.IdEspecialidad = c.IdEspecialidad
ORDER BY NEWID();
```

Pude recrear el error que resultó ser más evidente de lo que esperaba. Alguna de tus columnas de HoraInicio está declarada como `char(5)` y con una Collation (Intercalación según la página de MS) diferente al resto.

Simplemente hay que agregar el COLLATE a la columna necesaria.

```
WITH TablaCTE AS (
    SELECT cu.idespecialidad,convert(char(5),cu.horainicio, 108) as HoraInicio,cu.fecha FROM cupos cu
    inner join Especialidades es on es.IdEspecialidad = cu.idespecialidad
    EXCEPT
    SELECT ci.IdEspecialidad,ci.HoraInicio COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AS,ci.Fecha FROM Citas ci
    inner join Especialidades ess on ess.IdEspecialidad = ci.idespecialidad
    EXCEPT
    SELECT es1.IdEspecialidad,cb.HoraInicio,cb.Fecha FROM CitasBloqueadas cb
    inner join Especialidades es1 on es1.Nombre = cb.Especialidad  COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AS
)
SELECT count(IdEspecialidad) as Cupos, IdEspecialidad
FROM TablaCTE
GROUP BY IdEspecialidad;
```

Te recomiendo que homogeneíces tus columnas para utilizar la misma COLLATION en todas tus cadenas de caracteres y prevengas estos problemas. Voy a buscar un script que hice hace tiempo para realizar el cambio.

Comment: Deberías vender esa bola de cristal. Se ve que funciona bien :)